# How to check the type of a Parameter in an Expression Tree (similar to 'is' keyword)

Tags: c#, expression-trees, typechecking

How do I check the type of a Parameter in an Expression Tree (and get the Expression Tree equivalent of a `bool` if it the right type)? If it were normal code, I would do this:

```
if(myObj is int)
```

I see there is a `Expression.Convert` method but this converts the object instead of just checking its type.

**EDIT:** I found the answer, you use a `Expression.TypeIs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Expression.TypeIs` method :

```
var isExpression = Expression.TypeIs(parameterExpression, typeof(SomeType));
```

Comment: I found the answer already, but I'll give you rep for being nice and answering :)